# Unable to access VCAP SERVICES in PCF in Spring XML based application

Tags: java, spring, jpa, cloud, pcf

I'm trying to access VCAP Services which PCF provides but unable to do so.
I have created a USER DEFINED SERVICE for DB connection. But unable to get those values in my application.properties file.

***This is not a Spring Boot application.***

```
spring.datasource.url=${cloud.services.cgbpm-dev-sql.url}
spring.datasource.username=${cloud.services.cgbpm-dev-sql.username}
spring.datasource.password=${cloud.services.cgbpm-dev-sql.password}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=${cloud.services.cgbpm-dev-sql.driver-class-name}
```

I'm getting this error-

```
2019-03-20T21:29:51.69+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'cloud.services.cgbpm-dev-sql.driver-class-name' in string value "${cloud.services.cgbpm-dev-sql.driver-class-name}"
```

Comment: [vcap services](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/cloud/CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor.html). it should be `vcap.services.servicename.credentials`.

Comment: @Barath that works with spring boot actually..thanks